# Finding which packages control network interfaces?

Tags: debian, networking, upstart

I have a debian package that I'm running on startup.

I'm using upstart and I think I need to [add a dependency](https://askubuntu.com/a/450947/135947) to the upstart config:

```
start on someProgram
```

I'm not sure which program, but I'm not using `network-manager`, it's disabled. I'm doing something like this:

```
ethernet=$(ifconfig -a | grep Ethernet | grep ^e | cut -d' ' -f1)
wifi=$(ifconfig -a | grep wl | cut -d' ' -f1)
ping -I $ethernet -c 1 8.8.8.8 \
  || ping -I $wifi -c 1 8.8.8.8 \
  || echo "not online"
```

Problem is `ifconfig` doesn't always show the `$wifi` interface because the program has turned on too early in the startup process.

Also `ping -I $ethernet -c 1 8.8.8.8` fails when it should succeed.

If I do `sleep 30` then `ping` it works fine.

Does anyone know what package I should be waiting for to get this to work as expected?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on an embedded device.

```
3.0.36+ #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 31 19:17:57 EDT 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

---

I thought I had an answer:

> I'm finding that the network interfaces can be referenced directly
>   instead of a package:
>
> ```
> start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
> ```
>
> I'd still like to improve it slightly for my case.
>
> Since I'd rather wait for wlan than eth but I'm not sure if I can use
>   a wild card like: `IFACE=wlan*`

But it seems this doesn't wait for the interface to be available to `ifconfig` instead it waits for that interface to have an active Internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a workaround using an upstart pre-start script:

```
pre-start script
    while [ -z "$(ifconfig | grep wlan)" ]
    do
        sleep 1
    done
    sleep 5
end script
```